# "Не()способных": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

(Не)способных работать, (не)способных мыслить - слитно или раздельно? Вроде есть зависимое слово, но это же не причастие...

Answer (score 3):

Иногда слитное или раздельное написание не с прилагательным определяется возможностью двоякого толкования текста: Яблоко невкусное (утверждается, что оно плохое). —Яблоко не вкусное(отрицается, что оно вкусное). 
Наличие пояснительных слов, как правило, не влияет на слитное написание не с прилагательными.
Посмотрим и на значения прилагательного:Способный - 1-обладающий способностями, одарённый;2-могущий что-то сделать.

Он туп, к книжному учению неспособен. Они неспособны мыслить, неспособны работать, неспособны управлять. - утверждается тупость, неспособность.
Он человек, физически не способный работать. - отрицается способность работать, возможность работать (вовсе не обязательно из-за тупоумия).

Так что зависит от того, какое значение придаётся в тексте. В парах с краткими прилагательными неспособен - не способен чаще встречается раздельное написание, там больше чувствуется отрицание положительного признака: не может что-то сделать.

Comment: В контексте"Из них можно сделать роботов, не способных мыслить самостоятельно" я бы тоже отдала предпочтение раздельному написанию: отрицается способность мыслить самостоятельно

Answer (score 0):

Но если автор хочет подчеркнуть отрицание, то раздельно. Нужен контекст.

> роботов, (не) способных мыслить самостоятельно

Здесь всё-таки отрицание. Я бы написала раздельно

Comment: Контекст: 

Из них можно сделать роботов, (не) способных мыслить самостоятельно.

Answer (score -1):

Конечно, это прилагательные и пишутся слитно, так как нет противопоставления